# ST_ClusterDBSCAN function and minpoints parameter definition

Tags: postgresql, cluster-analysis, postgis, window-functions, dbscan

I've spent the last 2 days trying to figure out what's wrong with my clustering query. It did seem to work correctly but after some more detailed testing, I was confused seeing that some clusters haven't got created even if they evidently should be.

So initially I was assuming that:

```
ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 1, minpoints := 4) OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(country_code, elevation_ft, height_ft, obstacle_type))
```

would result in clustering points that have the same "PARTITION BY" attributes and the minimum group would need to have 4 points (**including core point**) in eps distance. According to the docs:
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html

> An input geometry will be added to a cluster if it is either:
>
> - A "core" geometry, that is within eps distance of at least minpoints input geometries **(including itself)** or
> - A "border" geometry, that is within eps distance of a core geometry.  its surrounding area with radius eps.

But it seems that it's not exactly true. It seems that in order to cluster 4 points (like minpoints parameter is set), the grouping query:

```
OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(country_code, elevation_ft, height_ft, obstacle_type))
```

needs to result in at least five objects to let clst_id to be created for other four.. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.point_table
(   
    point_sys_id serial primary key,--System generated Primary Key - Asset Cache
    point_id bigint,
    geom geometry(Point,4326),--Geometry Field
    country_code varchar(4),--Country Code
    elevation_ft numeric(7,2),--Elevation in Feet
    height_ft numeric(7,2),--Height in Feet
    obstacle_type varchar(50)--Obstacle Type
)

INSERT INTO point_table(point_id, geom, country_code, elevation_ft, height_ft, obstacle_type)
VALUES
(1, '0101000020E6100000E4141DC9E5934B40D235936FB6193940', 'ARE', 100, 50, 'BUILDING'),
(2, '0101000020E6100000C746205ED7934B40191C25AFCE193940', 'ARE', 100, 50, 'BUILDING'),
(3, '0101000020E6100000C780ECF5EE934B40B6BE4868CB193940', 'ARE', 100, 50, 'BUILDING'),
(4, '0101000020E6100000A97A358FA5AF4B4074A0C65B724C3940', 'ARE', 100, 50, 'BUILDING'), -- this point is outside of the cluster distance (eps)
(5, '0101000020E6100000ABB2EF8AE0934B404451A04FE4193940', 'ARE', 100, 50, 'BUILDING')

select ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 0.000906495804256269, minpoints := 4) OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(country_code, elevation_ft, height_ft, obstacle_type)) as clst_id, 
       point_id, geom, country_code, elevation_ft, height_ft, obstacle_type
from point_table
--where point_id != 4
```

Running clustering query agains all five points works fine. But once you exclude seemingly irrelevant point_id = 4 (which is outside of eps distance anyway) the clustering stops working (clst_id becomes null), even if still theoretically 4 needed points (according to the docs) are in place.

Once I change the minpoints parameter to 3, clustering works fine for those 4 neighbor points.

Can someone confirm my conclusion that ST_ClusterDBSCAN is not correct or give some good explanation for this behavior?

**EDIT**:
I've submitted a ticket to PostGIS directly: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4853
and it seems that this has been fixed from 3.1 version :)

[image]